# Is firebase a server that has a mobile service

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

for one of my assignments I have to make an **Android app and I have to use a server and a service which can be a mobile service or a web service.** So I was thinking of **using Firebase** as it is real time and have some good features.

BUT

I want to know for the above requirements of my assignment is Firebase suitable.

Also, I have been told to submit a deployment unit, I am guessing the deployment unit in this case is the APK file. Am I right?

**EDIT**

In my assignment specification it says **"Server deployed in the cloud and server must be micro-service or web-service or mobile-service of your choice"** which made me choose Firebase. But I am confused if firebase's server is in the cloud and if it uses any of the services mentioned above :/

Comment: Have you tried to look this ?

Comment: What is a "mobile service". You can make HTTP requests from a mobile device no different than a web app

Comment: @cricket_007 in my Assignment specification it says "Server deployed in the cloud and server must be micro-service or web-service or mobile-service of your choice" which made me choose Firebase. But I am confused if firebase's server is in the cloud and if it uses any of the services mentioned above :/

Comment: Obviously it is in the cloud if you don't have it manually installed on a server yourself and is managed by an external company

Comment: @cricket_007 Oh okay, but does it use any of the services mentioned in my assignment?

Comment: No one can answer that except Google engineers that maintain the services. I could be wrong, but almost all Google services are micro-services

Comment: @cricket_007 Oh okay. So just to get things confirmed. Firebase does have a server in the cloud, and the code we right after getting a reference of the db is a service...

Comment: Firebase isn't a server. Again, it's a platform (running across many servers)

Comment: @cricket_007 Roger that, Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Firebase has great services such as Realtime Database, Analytics, Storage, Remote Config, ... which help you to build your app.

The deployment unit in Android is ".APK" file. (If you are gonna develop a library, it will be ".AAR" file (Android ARchive file))

Comment: Thank You for your answer, btw is Firebase a server that uses a service such as mobile service?

Comment: @MinhazIrphan FIrebase is a PaaS (platform as a service)

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is a cloud-based technology that permits you to make with no server-side programming. It offers features like Realtime Database, storage options, Notifications, authentication options, hosting and more and there is no server side code required. Just put in the configurations and Firebase would handle it. Firebase lets you store user information and sync data between them in realtime.